# How to set Limit Number of Documents in a Form Library

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I have a form library and want to limit the number documents added to it. I want the library to have only one item in it. Let me know if there is some easiest way to do it. The documents are added via infopath form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out of the box way for this. why do you want to have such limitation ?

If you really need to do this, you can impose this via event handler. But there are questions:

What will happen to new documents being added - Will they be deleted , moved somewhere ?